# DatePicker DateSelected Command

Tags: xamarin.forms

Just wanted to confirm whether `DatePicker`'s `DateSelected` is not `Binding` possible like:

```
DateSelected="{Binding TargetDateSelectedCommand}"/>
```

To me it looks like `handler` has to be created in `.cs` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **possible**, you could have a try with [Turn Events into Commands with Behaviors](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/turn-events-into-commands-behaviors/).

Custom a  `Behavior<DatePicker>` class as follows:

```
public class DatePickerSelectedItemBehavior: Behavior<DatePicker>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(DatePickerSelectedItemBehavior), null);
    public static readonly BindableProperty InputConverterProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Converter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(DatePickerSelectedItemBehavior), null);

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public IValueConverter Converter
    {
        get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(InputConverterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputConverterProperty, value); }
    }

    public DatePicker AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(DatePicker bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        AssociatedObject = bindable;
        bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
        bindable.DateSelected += DatePickerItemSelected;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(DatePicker bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;
        bindable.DateSelected -= DatePickerItemSelected;
        AssociatedObject = null;
    }

    void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnBindingContextChanged();
    }

    void DatePickerItemSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Command == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        object parameter = Converter.Convert(e, typeof(object), null, null);
        if (Command.CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            Command.Execute(parameter);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;
    }
}
```

Then used in **Xaml**:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:SelectedItemEventArgsToSelectedItemConverter x:Key="SelectedItemConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<DatePicker >
    <DatePicker.Behaviors>
        <local:DatePickerSelectedItemBehavior Command="{Binding OutputAgeCommand}"
                                                Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemConverter}" />
    </DatePicker.Behaviors>
</DatePicker>
```

Here is the **SelectedItemEventArgsToSelectedItemConverter.cs**:

```
public class SelectedItemEventArgsToSelectedItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var eventArgs = value as DateChangedEventArgs;
        return eventArgs.NewDate;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: buti was ment that by default it's not aavailable right? Thanks for this answer i will take a look later

Comment: @Arie Yes, you can not use it with binding by default. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datepicker?view=xamarin-forms) `DatePicker` does not have any command properties.  `DateSelected` is a `DateTime`, not a command